# How Can I Check A String Whether It Does Exists In A The Given String Or Does Not?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I am currently working on a database project that uses platform MySQL. Project includes tables such as course, instructor, researchArea etc. What I really need is a trigger that checks how many words from "researchArea keywords" are in the given text. Text is going to be pulled from another table which named course. With the result I am planing to get a integer matching percentage value and with the value, I planned to insert the calculated value into "matchingvalue" which is a attribute in instructor table, a attribute to describe the relation of the course content between the instructor.

I have a big lack of scripting experience and syntax information in sql already and I couldn't even think a solution to solve this thing. Any ideas to create a trigger for this query or function whatever it is?

Image of the EER

[image: 1]

Comment: why a trigger?  what do you want to happen when?  please describe that in some detail and show your schema

Comment: I changed the post to fix some meaning problems, make sure to check out before read my main question.

I want to create a trigger just because it is a project requirement that have to show to my instructor. I will post the tables and schema soon, but the schema might have some issues, keep that in mind. @ysth

Comment: I thought I explained the main thing that I want tho, simply I want a function that takes some string and checks that  if given strings exists in a another given text.

Comment: triggers happen when you do something (insert/update/delete a row).  what is the thing you are doing that fires this trigger?

Comment: Inserting keywords to a course table should trigger the calculation.

Comment: instr is the function that checks if a string contains another string.

Comment: For example a course tuple inserted and within CDes attribute took a value with the operation. After that, trigger should initialize and take keywords of the instructor of the course and calculate a value to describe if instructor is suitable for the course or not.

Comment: I saw instr, does it return boolean values or just index of the string that given? As I saw it return the index, not the count or a boolean value.

Comment: `instr(yourtext,yourkeyword) > 0` would be a boolean